# Unable to setup episerver default application (failed to attach the episerver database)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, web-config, sql-server-2014, episerver

I'm trying to integrate Episerver into my visual studio project. I've downloaded the Episerver CMS extension through NuGet manager and everything went well.. The issue here is that when I try to access the episerver CMS panel like this:

```
localhost:port/episerver/cms I get the following error

Directory lookup for the file EPiServerDB_ae17da15.mdf failed with the operating system error 5(Access is denied.).Cannot attach the file EPiServerDB_ae17da15.mdf as database 'EPiServerDB_ae17da15'.
```

And this is my connection string:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="EPiServerDB" connectionString="Data Source=.;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|EPiServerDB_ae17da15.mdf;Initial Catalog=EPiServerDB_ae17da15;Connection Timeout=60;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

What am I doing wrong here? Can someone help me out?

Comment: Are you running your site in IIS Express? Do you run your VS instance under Administrator account?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="EPiServerDB" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|EPiServerDB_ae17da15.mdf;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Using the MDF-database do require you to have SQL Server LocalDB installed, I believe it is available as an install option of Visual Studio as well.

**== Edit ==**

If you are missing the MDF-file simply create a new using Visual Studio, create a new item and select the SQL Server Database

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As Erik mentioned you will need to have SQL Server LocalDB installed to attach the .mdf file if you go with that option. If you already have the "full" SQL-server installed you can create an empty database, add the relevant connectionString and run

> Initialize-EPiDatabase

in the package manager console. Now you don't need to install LocalDB.

Comment: LocalDB is installed together with VS2015.